# Uncaught ReferenceError when using the asset pipeline and pjax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

Ok, this this sounds like a newbie mistake... but I can't seem to figure out what's going on.
I'm relatively new to Rails 3.1, coffeescript and the asset pipeline in general, so I'm having a bit of trouble figuring this one out.

Anyway, here is the problem.

In my Users index.html.erb file I have a button which will load a new user form through ajax. The code to load the form sits in users.js.coffee and the button has an onClick method referring to the function that does that work, like so.

index.html.erb

```
<%= button_tag "New User", :id => "btn_new_user", :onClick => "loadNewUserForm()", :path => "#{new_user_path}" %>
```

users.js.coffee

```
loaded = false

loadNewUserForm = ->
  if not loaded
    @path = $('#btn_new_user').attr("path")
    $("#new-users-container").load(@path)
    loaded = true
```

for some reason, when I click on the New User button I keep getting

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: loadNewUserForm is not defined
```

I tried binding the function to the click event of the button in the document.ready (declared in users.js.coffee) but the problem with that is that it's not being called because I'm using pjax.

I think I'm not understanding the way asset pipeline works or something...

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt go to the generated JavaScript to see what's going on. You'll probably see something like this:

```
(function() {
  // Your code here
}).call(this);
```

This is the standard mechanism used in Javascript to avoid namespace collision (Coffeescript does it by default), so objects are not visible outside this file unless you explicitly attach them to a global object (`window` in the browser, `exports` in node.js, ...).

By the way, note that you are not following the commonly accepted [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) guidelines: you should set events using JavaScript, not with inline events in HTML tags. Some references: [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/) and [here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/).

Comment: excellent, this is exactly what's going on. I figured that was not the correct way to do it because binding the events in JS code is definitely cleaner than specifying an onclick function. Thanks!

Comment: another quick question I think its related. In order to do unobtrusive JS, normally code is binded in the document.ready. However, I'm using pjax and document.ready only runs once (when the elements I want to bind to are not on screen yet). Is there another technique to bind the elements to their events? I'm thinking when the user clicks on the menu item it triggers an init function or something.

Comment: @HectorVillarreal If possible, use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of binding events directly to the elements.

Comment: That did the trick, awesome. This is a very good method to know! gotta love Stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @Trevor: or selectors.on(event, callback) for latests jquery versions.